# Python: How to ensure the last line of code has completed?

Tags: python, file

I'm doing some kind of complex operation, it needs the last line(s) of code has completed, then proceed to the next step, for example. I need to ensure a file has written on the disk then read it. Always, the next line of code fires while the file haven't written on disk , and thus error came up. How resolve this?

Okay..

```
picture.save(path, format='png')
time.sleep(1)       #How to ensure the last step has finished
im = Image.open(path)
```

Comment: Without some code showing the problem there's no way to know what's wrong.

Comment: Step one: post the code in question.

Comment: If picture.save isn't asynchronous or multi-threaded behind the scenes, it will always complete before the next line executes. Is this with some library that saves things in the background?

Comment: What is the function definition / where did you get the function `picture.save`?

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you using PIL Image?

Comment: The disk may be slower than the CPU executes my code, this is the biggest problem

Comment: Yes, I'm using PIL image, the error I got is"Can't find the file at blah... blah..". If I added time.sleep(1), then the problem gone!

Comment: Are you writing to a local disk? Or onto a network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do anything unless the previous operation is asynchronous. In your case, you should check picture.save's documentation to see if it specifically define as asynchronous. By default everything is synchronize. Each line will complete before it continues to next operation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just want to check is that there's a file at `path` before trying to open it.

You *could* check for the path's existence before trying to open it and sleep for a bit if it doesn't exist, but that sleep might not be long enough, and you still might have a problem opening the file.

You really should just enclose the open operation in a try-except block:

```
try:
    im = Image.open(path)
except [whatever exception you are getting]:
    # Handle the fact that you couldn't open the file
    im = None # Maybe like this..
```